# Fire event right after event was sent but before it was completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following situation. I need to fire some event right after my ajax request was sent but before it has completed. Looking at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) I see whole bunch of events: `beforeSend`, `complete`, `error`, `success`, `done`, `always`. But there is nothing that looks like event I want.

So is it possible to do?

Just to highlight **what exactly do I want to achieve**:

```
    var foo = 'BAR';
    $.post('serverURL', {
        T: foo,
    }, function(data){
        //...
    }, 'json');

    foo = '';
```

So I have a code similar to this. And the way it works is perfectly fine (it sends correct `foo` to the server and than right after it send it it modifies it). It modifies it not when the ajax is done/finished/successed/failed, but right after it fires.

I want to put this modification `foo = ''` in a callback, (like success callback). Just to answer why do I need to do this: some people when they read a code, decide to "improve" it by moving `foo = ''` somewhere else (before the ajax) and thus introduce the bug which is hard to spot. Comments like // Do not move it do not help.

Comment: what are `some event`?

Comment: @Salvador Dali See http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ at "Example: Chain tasks" Hope this helps

Comment: @Pilot any function. Something that you would put in `success` or `done`. I know that I can put it right after ajax call, but is there anything else?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, but deffered is something that happens after ajax finished.

Comment: @Pilot beforeSend is called before the ajax will be sent.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Completely wrong..You can attach event handler to Defered object

Comment: @Pilot hm... can you please show me how can I use deferred to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: @SalvadorDali you might want to play round with `xhr` object method `onreadystatechange`

Comment: @Salvador Dali See answer. Hope this helps

Comment: @Salvador Dali Have you tried updated answer? `foo` as function? returns `""` default; when executed with `$.post()` function called with argument; though `default` return value not really change. Thanks for sharing. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There exists a global jQuery ajax event handler:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){   ...    });
```

, which is called when the first Ajax request starts.

Comment: ajaxStart will be executed for every ajax that will be called.

Comment: You could bind the ajaxStart into a specific element, as seen here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191485/how-to-call-ajaxstart-on-specific-ajax-calls ), but not clear if this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
formData = {
    param1: "param1"
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://example.com/detail.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    beforeSend: function() {
        //before handler
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //success handler
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        //complete handler
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

Comment: No, all of them will execute after ajax will finish. Some error, when it was unsuccessful.

Comment: I already answered to someone in the comments that beforeSend fires an event right before the ajax have started. Not right after it started.