# JQuery getJSON Disable Global Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to **disable global events** inside a JQuery `$.getJSON` function ?

[The documentation](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/#content) only mention that the global property is available for an `$.ajax` call, but nothing about `$.getJSON`.

There reason I want to deactivate is that I have a global `ajaxStart` event that I want to not handle the async JSON file reading.

Any possible solution ? Do I have to convert the `$.getJSON` function to an `$.ajax` call ?

[This is what I am trying to solve but for an async `$.getJSON` file event.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624170/19112855)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no available way to disable global events in a `$.getJSON`.

I had to convert it to regular AJAX call from [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success).

Changed this

```
$.getJSON(strUrl, function(response_data) {...
```

to this

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: strUrl,
    global: false,
    success: function(response_data) {...
```