# jQuery UI Ajax Tabs Loading not showing

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI Vertical Tabs and the content is loaded via AJAX. I tried almost everything from posts around here, and nothing helped me so far .. :/

I want to display a css3 loading animation placed in `<div id="loading-image">...</div>`. So far almost nothing is happening.

My code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#messages_tabs_div" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui);
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html("Couldn't load your messages. Try refreshing your page."+
                    " If you think this is bug you can help us by submitting it at bugs@go-out-sport.com "  );
            });
            ui.jqXHR.complete(function(response){                
                console.log(response);                    
            });
        },
        disabled: [6],
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert('ASDAD');
        }
    }).addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#messages_tabs_div li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
});

//jQuery MINE
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading-image').hide();
    //Set loading bar for all ajax requests
    $('#loading-image').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
        alert('AJAXXX');
        $(this).show();
    }).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });    

    $('#loading-image').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
        alert('TABSSSSS');
        $(this).show();
    }).bind('tabsload', function(event, ui) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

The only thing I get is the `AJAX alert`. I tried removing `$('#loading-image').hide();` and the loading was always there.

Please help ....

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please add html (the header and the content should be in the same container), if you would like to separate header and content you could use [jquerytools tabs](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a global ajax loading..

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loading").fadeOut(300);
}).ajaxSuccess(function() {
});
```

but, if you want personalize for multiple events, see this questions:

[How to call .ajaxStart() on specific ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191485/how-to-call-ajaxstart-on-specific-ajax-calls)

[jQuery should I use multiple ajaxStart/ajaxStop handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061922/jquery-should-i-use-multiple-ajaxstart-ajaxstop-handling)

Comment: It's not working .. that's what I'm saying .. I've tried this already .. and I don't know where is the problem. Even when the loading is showed when I click on any other tab it's hiding .. FOREVER .. :/

Comment: try to make some online demo, and I try to help you better - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Found my mistake, I've put the loading div in one of the tabs and when I switch the tab it disappears .. I'm stupid :D Thanks for the help anyway : )