# JQuery Progress bar for multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading, progress

I have multiple ajax requests on my page and for each i want to have different progress bars to be shown till the response.In the code below, "second" progress bars is not shown on the first click, it appears at third. What could be the reason ?

Here you can check jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/narya/zheeuoyu/#&togetherjs=vxl7Hllw5m

and here is the xml file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oxkmj8bgt0muma/testAja.xml?dl=0

"TestB.xml" is copy of this file if you need to check, you can just copy&paste. Please consider to use an xml file larger than 400 Kb to be able to observe loading bars.
Thanks

Edited Code:23.06.2016 11:15

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#second").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#loadCompCountry').css("display", "block");
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loadCompCountry').css("display", "none");
                },
                type: "GET",
                url: "testAja.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $("#CompCountry").append("<ul></ul>");
                    $(xml).find('CD').each(function () {
                        var cdCountry = $(this).find('COUNTRY').text();
                        var cdComp = $(this).find('COMPANY').text();
                        $("<li></li>").html(cdCountry + ' , ' + cdComp).appendTo("#CompCountry");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("top req ");
                }
            });    
        });

        $("#third").click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               beforeSend: function(){
                   $("#loadTitleArtist").css("display", "block");
               },
               complete: function(){
                   $("#loadTitleArtist").css("display", "none");
               },
                type: "GET",
                url: "testB.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $("#titleArtist").append("<ul></ul>");
                    $(xml).find('CD').each(function () {
                        var cdTitle = $(this).find('TITLE').text();
                        var cdArtist = $(this).find('ARTIST').text();
                        $("<li></li>").html(cdTitle + ' , ' + cdArtist).appendTo("#titleArtist")
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("nonono ");
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please put your html code also and is it possible to add jsfiddle link?

Comment: Thanks, i put it on jsfiddle with all related files except xml and shared it via dropbox.

Comment: And another point is: I wonder why when I clicked the button again progress bar does not appear again. It's stored in local storage or am i missing something and it should be processed again even it's stored.

Comment: I think [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1062007/4373584) is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your search but it's not familiar with my situation. It seems similar but I hava different problem above